# Date Time format in Flutter dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm

Tags: dart, flutter

[image: My Date-Time format at the moment is this]

By using this :

```
Text(new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(values[index]["start_time"]*1000).toString(),
```

I am getting the type of format attached in the picture, however I was wondering if I could get it in `dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm`??

Comment: check [this link](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Comment: @PratikPrajapati that documentation is horrible. It is very difficult to find a specific format and most of them don't even have an example of what it produces. They need to take a lesson from [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) on how to document DateTime formatting.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

If you use the [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

```
final f = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm');

Text(f.format(new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(values[index]["start_time"]*1000)));
```

Comment: Thank you, all works fine, however I was wondering how to make it AM or PM format too??

Comment: hey @HeyabRedda , if you check the docs (https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) you'll find the table with all formatting options.

Answer (score 71):

Use [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

The following code converts `31/12/2000 23:59` to `12/31/2000 11:59 PM`

```dart
var inputFormat = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
var inputDate = inputFormat.parse('31/12/2000 23:59'); // <-- dd/MM 24H format

var outputFormat = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a');
var outputDate = outputFormat.format(inputDate);
print(outputDate); // 12/31/2000 11:59 PM <-- MM/dd 12H format
```

Answer (score 28):

First install the [pub.dev/packages/intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package in your pubspec.yaml

```
   intl: ^0.16.1
```

**Then use**

```
   final df = new DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a');
   int myvalue = 1558432747;
   print(df.format(new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(myvalue*1000)));
```

**Output**

> 21-05-2019 10:59 AM

Answer (score 17):

You can use ***`date_format`*** plugin available here https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/date_format

Then to convert,

```
formatDate(DateTime.now(), [dd, '/', mm, '/', yyyy, ' ', HH, ':', nn])
```

Comment: This package seems lighter and better maintained than the intl package

Answer (score 8):

```
/// Get date as a string for display.
String getFormattedDate(String date) {
  /// Convert into local date format.
  var localDate = DateTime.parse(date).toLocal();

  /// inputFormat - format getting from api or other func.
  /// e.g If 2021-05-27 9:34:12.781341 then format should be yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
  /// If 27/05/2021 9:34:12.781341 then format should be dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm
  var inputFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
  var inputDate = inputFormat.parse(localDate.toString());

  /// outputFormat - convert into format you want to show.
  var outputFormat = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
  var outputDate = outputFormat.format(inputDate);

  return outputDate.toString();
}
```

Comment: what if i want to send the "2021-05-27 9:34:12.781341" time format to API. how should I do it?

Answer (score 5):

If you use the [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl):

```
var date = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(miliseconds * 1000)
DateFormat(DateFormat.YEAR_MONTH_DAY, 'pt_Br').format(date.toUtc())
```

**Output:**
10 de abril de 2020

Answer (score 3):

## try this

**Method:**

```
    getFormatedDate(_date) {
      var inputFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
      var inputDate = inputFormat.parse(_date);
      var outputFormat = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
    return outputFormat.format(inputDate);
    }
```

**Call:**

```
getFormatedDate(_start_date)// simple date in string format
```

**output:**

```
24/05/2021
```

Comment: `DateFormat` is not accessible. i think you need to add the dependencies for this library.

Comment: add the intl package

Comment: sure next time i'm try it.

Answer (score 2):

```dart
var dateInFormatText = widget.snapshot["date"].toString().split("/");

DateTime dateResult = new DateTime.utc(
int.parse(dateInFormatText[2]),     
int.parse(dateInFormatText[1]), 
int.parse(dateInFormatText[0]));
```

Comment: Please add more information to the answer to make it more comprehensive.

Comment: You can just get the string to split and create a datetime object dd/MM/YYYY.         Você pode apenas pegar a string fazer um split e criar um objeto datetime com o padrão dd/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score 2):

Just need to follow 5 steps:

Step 1: locate **pubspec.yaml** file and check dependencies of your application. if it doesn't have **intl** dependency created yet, make sure to add in your **pubspec.yaml** file.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.18.0<you can change to desired version>
```

Step2: Just click CMD+S for MAC OS or Cntrl+S for Windows.

Step 3: observe the bottom toolbar of your editor if you are using VS Code. it will show a message to say it's installing extension

Step 4: Make sure to import the package in your class

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Step 5: if you want to display date on Text Widget use below code else just use DateFormatter

```
Text(DateFormat.yMMMEd().format(item.date)) // this extension gives lots of formats. feel free to use based on your requirement.
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [date_format](https://pub.dev/packages/date_format) package to format dates in flutter.

```
import 'package:date_format/date_format.dart';

final formattedStr = formatDate(DateTime.now(), [dd, '/', mm, '/', yyyy, ' ', HH, ':' nn]);

//02-03-2021
```

Answer (score 0):

If DateFormat() is not working in your case you must add "intl" package by running this command on your terminal:

```
flutter pub get intl
```

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since almost every other answer posted that same solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should [vote it up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score -1):

All supportive date formate in flutter you can refer this link flutter.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

```
var inputDateFormat = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
var inputDate = inputDateFormat.parse('25/12/2000 20:50'); // 24Hour format

var outputDateFormat = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a');
var outputDate = outputDateFormat.format(inputDate);
print(outputDate); // 12/25/2000 20:50 PM // 24Hour format
```