# Flutter - Can´t format Datetime

Tags: datetime, flutter

The error is simple

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateFormat.d().format(DateTime.now().toString())
```

Return

> The method 'd' isn't defined for the class 'DateFormat'. Try
>   correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a
>   method named 'd'.

Is clear what  happen but how can i fix it?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date Time format in Flutter dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50758072/date-time-format-in-flutter-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmm)

Comment: in the documentation  : DateFormat.d([dynamic locale]) , maybe you need to put a value inside the d() method .

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Get current day? For example "Monday"?

Comment: Exactly, this is i want it-

Comment: Try DateTime.now().weekday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use this to get a day of week (like at monday)

```
DateFormat.EEEE().format(DateTime.now())
```

With intl: ^0.16.0 in pubspec.yaml

You need user DateFormat from intl library. Check where that DateFormat class is import

Comment: The method 'EEEE' isn't defined for the class 'DateFormat'.. I have intl in pubspec.yaml

Comment: That others imports you have in the same file you want this method

Answer (score 2):

You need DateFormat for only complex formatting. For this kind of simple operation, you can use the properties of the DateTime class as following:

`DateTime.now().weekday`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
DateFormat("EEEE").format(DateTime.now().toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

The format() method receives an object of type DateTime no String. I tried to

```
print(DateFormat.d().format(DateTime.now()));
```

and they worked correctly.I don't understand why it tells you that the d() method is undefined. Have you checked that the package matters well and that you can access the implement also from the d() method by pressing cmd + click on the method?