# how to show timestamp from firestore in dd/mm/yy format in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

how to show datetime(timestamp format) form firebase firestore in (dd/mm/yy, hh:mm:ss) in flutter.
please see the images attached[firebase firestore data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZziV.png)
and my code is [my code in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKI5Z.png)

Comment: I think this could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50758072/date-time-format-in-flutter-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmm

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call `toDate()` function to the dateTime or your firebase timestamp.
You can also convert them into desired format by using DateFormat class
Here is a small function which will return time like 12:37 AM :

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';   //add this import statement for using DateTime class

String getTime(var time) {
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm:ss aa');  //your date format here
    var date = time.toDate();
    return formatter.format(date);
  }
```

This function will convert your timestamp object to provided format
eg.: `July 23, 2021 at 9:22:29 PM UTC+5:30` -> `23/07/2021, 9:22:29 PM`
You can refer this [document](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) for detailed date formatting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Created another widget and passed Timestamp value to that widget.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can first parse the date to get a `DateTime` object by using `DateTime.parse(string_from_firebase)`.

Then use the `DateFormat` class from the `intl` package.

```dart
final DateTime dateToBeFormatted = DateTime.parse(string);
final df = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
final formatted = df.format(dateToBeFormatted);
```