# how to hardcode API integration true/false

Tags: flutter, api

I want to hard code is_verified field as true into my dart code. because I'm planning to implement that part later. how can I do that. below is the code I have implemented for API integration. (not including (is_verified)field.) how to hardcode this field. also when I CLICK Signup button the API calling part is not working. wanna know suggestions on that as well. [full signup.dart code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1X1d08RYt19OGF9G3pLMcOUapXQnexJboj5O2VW7bfGw/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]  [![enter image description here] [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGhsj.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGhsj.png)  [image]

```
Future UserSignUp(File file) async {
  String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;

  dioo.FormData data = dioo.FormData.fromMap({
    "image": await dioo.MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path,
        filename: fileName, contentType: MediaType.parse('image/jpg')),
    'userName': userName,
    'email': email,
    'mobileNumber': mobileNumber,
    'password': password,
    'dob':dob,

  });

  print(email);
  print(userName);
  print(image);
  print(data);
  try {
    var response = await Dio().post(BASE_API + "user/register",
        data: data,
        options: Options(headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}));

    print(response);
    if (response.data["message"] == "Successfully signed up .") {
      Get.snackbar(
        "Message",
        "Please check your email to verify your account",
        backgroundColor: buttontext.withOpacity(0.5),
        colorText: textWhite,
      );
      Get.to(const LoginScreen());
    } else if (response.data["code"] == 200) {
      Get.snackbar("Message", "Email Adresss is already exist.",
          backgroundColor: buttontext.withOpacity(0.5),
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: Colors.grey,
          colorText: textWhite,
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.error_outline_outlined,
            color: Colors.red,
            size: 30,
          ));
    } else {
      Get.snackbar("error", "No User Found");
    }
  } on DioError catch (e) {
    Get.snackbar("Error", "Something went wrong.Please contact admin",
        backgroundColor: buttontext.withOpacity(0.5),
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: Colors.grey,
        colorText: textWhite,
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.error_outline_outlined,
          color: Colors.red,
          size: 30,
        ));
    print(e.error.toString());
  }
}
```

//calling API

```
Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      child: MainButton("Sign Up"),
                      onTap: () async {
                        await UserSignUp(image!).then((value) {});

                        setState(() {
                          isLoading = false;
                          pointerIgnore = false;
                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add it to your post request

```
 dioo.FormData data = dioo.FormData.fromMap({
    "image": await dioo.MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path,
        filename: fileName, contentType: MediaType.parse('image/jpg')),
    'userName': userName,
    'email': email,
    'mobileNumber': mobileNumber,
    'password': password,
    'dob':dob,
"is_verified":true,...
```

Regarding your second

> also when I CLICK Signup button the API calling part is not working

Its difficult to tell, you can try using  `FormData.fromMap(` instead of  `dioo.FormData.fromMap(` as we have no clue what `dioo` means,

do the print statements print any data?

Comment: import 'package:dio/dio.dart' as dioo;  <<< I have imported this in top of the code.

Comment: I have updated the question with adding link to my full signup.dart code. can you please check kindly

Comment: I think its not working because of "dob" date of birth section.. any suggestions??

Comment: whats the error that the server gives?

Comment: E/flutter ( 9494): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Stack Overflow
E/flutter ( 9494): #0      dob (package:deltamax_fitness/Screens/signup_screen.dart:20:8)

Comment: No enough to debug, a random guess would be your server requires a formatted date ,  you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50758072/date-time-format-in-flutter-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmm

Comment: for now I want to hard code this birthday field for my API integration part. how can I do that